# grep file content from piped content

Tags: bash, grep

My dummy file looks like this

```
cat dummy_file 
    Tom
    Jerry
```

My piped content looks like this

```
COMMAND | 
    Tom Cat
    Jerry Mouse
    Spike Dog
```

I want to `grep` only those piped lines that are in `dummy_file`.
I can do this by creating intermediate file.

```
COMMAND > intermediate_file  
grep -w -F -f dummy_file intermediate file 
    Tom Cat 
    Jerry Mouse
```

How can I achieve this without creating an intermediate file and just grep'ing piped content?
Tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
COMMAND | 
    xargs -I {} grep -w -F -f dummy_file -- NO RESULT
```

Or this:

```
COMMAND |  
    xargs -I {} grep {} -w -F -f dummy_file -- ALL LINES ARE PRINTED
```

Comment: you can pipe the output of your command and call grep:
command | grep "regex"

Comment: e.g.:
ps aux | grep root

Comment: @Giudude Thanks! Though it would be more difficult.

Comment: @Giodude, can you post this as an answer and I will except it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` accepts input from stdin. Just do

```
COMMAND | grep -w -F -f dummy_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` command ;)

```
join --nonocheck-order -j1 <(COMMAND|sort) <(cat dummy_file|sort)|cut -d -f1 
# -j1 indicates the column to join in the two commands output
# it's equivalent to -11 -11 (first and second output)
# cut to print only the first column which is common to two orders
```

See `man join` for more details.

Comment: This only coincidentally works because `join` joins on a specified column, and while it is true that the particular data set has the required information in column 1, in general, the data might be looking for column 1 or 2 or 15 or ... and `join` really won't handle that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's why we need a complete dataset to propose an optimal solution. Otherwise I would have proposed an alternative... And it can still be used, even if it means making some adjustments (or completely change the solution).